Imagine a uniform rigid rod translating with a constant velocity on a horizontal frictionless surface. Suddenly, one end is hinged
Imagine a rigid one dimensional rod travelling on a smooth horizontal surface with a constant velocity. Suddenly, one end of the rod is hinged. Let's ignore impact, vibration and other non-ideal scenarios.
The rod starts rotating about the hinge immediately. Angular momentum is clearly conserved about the hinge point. But why is kinetic energy not conserved? We ignore any external field.
As opposed to a rod hanging freely, when a particle moving with a certain velocity comes and strikes the rod elastically. We do apply conservation of mechanical energy as well as angular momentum about the hinge point.
Why and how are the two scenarios different, when in both scenarios, a hinge force/impulse does act?

As opposed to a rod hanging freely, when a particle moving with a certain velocity comes and strikes the rod elastically.
An entirely different situation with the result that after the collision the particle has kinetic energy.
You have implied that the pivot does not move.
If you make the statement, let's ignore impact, vibration and other non-ideal scenarios, then the ideal model produces a contradiction because using it cannot account for the loss of kinetic energy.
So how might the ideal model be refined?
There may be others but two come to mind:
Assume that the pivot is attached to the Earth and the pivot (and Earth) move.
Assume that the pivot and/or rod bends (a) inelastically, or (b) elastically and starts to vibrate.
These two examples illustrate how the change of kinetic energy of the rod could be accounted for.
